# Create, Update and Delete arrays within arrays in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I have a schema like below..

```
courses : [{
          institution : String,
          from : Date,
          to : Date,
          overallScore :String,
          coursework : [{
           semesterName : String,
           score : String,
           from : Date,
           to : Date
          }]
}]
```

I know how to add a new coursework, but how do I update a value in a specific coursework based on the `_id` generated by each coursework, when there are multiple coursework items? Also, similarly, how do I delete a specific coursework from the larger collection?

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select an individual subdocument using the `.id()` method of a document array. Therefore, assuming an existing course document called `course`:

```
var coursework = course.coursework.id('id-of-coursework');
```

This document can then be deleted using:

```
coursework.remove();
```

Note that you must save the parent `course` document to persist changes to subdocuments.